# How to examine actual bitbake commands executed

Tags: openembedded, bitbake

Does bitbake store the shell-commands invoked (along the the path of invocation)? 
I can find the shell-command output in the log-files, but would like to view the actual command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. The `run.* log` files, found in the same directory as the `log.*` files are the are produced from the actual scripts that get executed by bitbake.  Everything you need is there.  They aren't trivial, because every aspect of the environment is set up, so they are cumbersome to read, but it's all there.

Have fun!